# Click text only once, not multiple times

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm using the website minecraft.tools to help create a book, in which the user clicks the text and is given an item. I created the text that says "> Click for Reward" and added a Click Event, that gives the user an item. But I want it when the user only clicks on it once, instead of multiple times, by which they can get the item repeatedly.

The command for Click Event is `/give @p economyinc:item_oneb`

Minecraft Java, playing version 1.14.4

Answer (score 2):

Create a dummy scoreboard objective, call it something along the lines of `hasClaimedReward`. When giving the item to the player, only give it to them if they have a `hasClaimedReward` score of 0:

```
/execute as @p if @s[scores={hasClaimedReward=..0}] run give @s <item>
```

Afterwards, set their hasClaimedReward score to 1.

It would be best to just make the book trigger a function to handle this.